# Tikz-dependency - two sentences, one tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have one sentence translated into two different languages which have the same dependency tree. Using `tikz-dependency`, I would like to display the sentences one over each other and display just one dependency tree rather than having two distinct figures.

```
  \begin{deptext}[column sep=1.8em]
          Ġanni \& tefa' \& l- \& ballun \& lil \& Marija \& . \\
      \end{deptext}
      \deproot{2}{ROOT}
      \depedge{2}{1}{SBJ}   
      \depedge{2}{5}{VC}
      \depedge{2}{7}{PU}
      \depedge{2}{4}{OBJ}
      \depedge{5}{6}{PC}
      \depedge{4}{3}{DET}
  \end{dependency}
```

The figure should result in:
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a second row in the `deptext` environment.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}

\begin{document}
\begin{dependency}
\begin{deptext}[column sep=1.8em]
          Ġanni \& tefa' \& l-  \& ballun \& lil \& Marija \& . \\
          John  \& threw \& the \& ball   \& at  \& Mary   \& . \\
\end{deptext}
      \deproot{2}{ROOT}
      \depedge{2}{1}{SBJ}   
      \depedge{2}{5}{VC}
      \depedge{2}{7}{PU}
      \depedge{2}{4}{OBJ}
      \depedge{5}{6}{PC}
      \depedge{4}{3}{DET}
\end{dependency} 
\end{document}
```